# change log level for only one of the subtask of a gradle build

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle build that I launch with

```
gradle clean build
```

I have a random bug when one of my test don't stop

The issue is, I can't figure which test it is . It's like 1 time for 40

Is there a way to put only the "test" task who is launched by "build" task with a bigger log level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the [`TestLoggingContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLoggingContainer.html) to suite your needs. For example, the below only shows stdout and stderr events:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent

tasks {
    test {
        events = [
            TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT,
            TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR
        ]
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can run Gradle commands with `--info` or `--stacktrace` for more details.